# MD5 checksum cross-platform compatibility

Tags: md5sum

I was just checking a md5 checksum to see if a file has downloaded correctly or not.

situation is like this.
I have downloaded a Linux iso file in Windows and checked the md5 with the Microsoft 'File checksum integrity verifier' utility. it is giving a different checksum from the one displayed on the linux OS website.

Q. IS the md5 checksum different (or same)  on different OS types ( winxp, win7, linux etc) ?

Answer (score 2):

No , the md5 sum will be the same on all OS.

See also:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Answer (score 2):

The utility can be different but its function of checking integrity will be same. In your case , The .iso file You have downloaded is faulty or corrupted. You have to download .iso file again.

Answer (score 2):

The Md5 sum is unique. It cannot be changed. The Windows Integrity Checked is not the reliable option. Use [Winmd5sum](http://www.winmd5.com/).